# Crie um algoritmo para ler um número inicial e outro final, mostrar os números pares deste intervalo, e também mostrar quantos números pares há

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

int ini,fini,i,par=0;
printf("ini ");
scanf("%d",&ini);

printf("fini ");
scanf("%d",&fini);
i=ini;


while (i<=fini) {

if (i % 2 == 0)  {
par+=1;
printf("%d\ " ,i );
printf("%d " ,par);

 }
i++;

}
// Eu gostaria que no final aparecesse somente o valor "5" 
 correspondente á quantidade de pares

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Prezado, uma possível solução para o seu problema de contar quantos números pares existe em um determinado intervalo é criar uma variável "qtdPares" começando com o valor 0 e incrementá-la dentro de um laço que checa se o número é par ou não.

Vou tentar exemplificar, mas me perdoe se eu errar a sintaxe pois não domino a linguagem que você está usando acima (acredito que seja C, certo?)

```
// Fora do escopo do while inicializa-se a variável de contagem:

int qtdPares = 0;

while (i<=fini) {

    if(ini % 2 == 0) {
  
         qtdPares += 1;    
     }

}
//Eu omiti as outras operações que você já fez.
```

Note que você incrementa a variável em 1 toda vez que a checagem de "é par?" retornar true, daí você vai ter a contagem de pares no seu programa.

Comment: Muito OBRIGADO PARCEIRO. Resolveu meu problema era isso que estava faltando mesmo!!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado, meu rei. Bons estudos!